# What kind of performance issue occurs if we uncheck Maintain connections across client requests in Coldfusion Datasource?

Tags: coldfusion, datasource, coldfusion-11

I am getting a frequent error

> Closed the physical connection

To rectify this, I want to uncheck `Maintain connections across client requests` in Coldfusion Datasource. 
If it is not recommended, then can I reduce Timeout and Interval? What is the recommended Timeout and Interval time?

Comment: Is there any scripts that run in the DB which kills connection in `sleep` status?

Comment: There is NO particular script which causes this error. I am getting this error only once in a month or week.

Comment: Are you getting that error on long running requests?

Comment: @Rojin Are you sure `Maintain connections across client requests` is not a good idea? It is the default when creating a datasource and I have worked on some large systems with this checked. IFAIK, the word client refers to the connection from CF to the DB, not the browser to the DB.

Comment: CF's connection pool ("Maintain connections across client requests") works perfectly fine. The only reason for disabling it, is having multiple concurrent systems contesting for connections on your database server, so serving connections need to be closed as soon as possible.

Comment: @RRK There is no such long-running requests. The Longest Transaction query takes 5 seconds. Is there any chance of causing the error 'Closed the physical connection' due to firewall issue? Because the Database is in another server.

Comment: @JamesAMohler I made a typo there. What I meant to say was that to keep check on for `Maintain connections across client requests`.